# MacBook Pro water damage short circuit (2019 16 inch)

Tags: macbook-pro, repair, damage

Unfortunately I recently spilled water on my MacBook Pro 2019. It has the following specs: https://business.currys.co.uk/catalogue/computing/laptops/macbook/apple-macbook-pro-16-2019-intel-core-i7-512-gb-space-grey/N280920W .
I only spilled a few drops of water on it, landing around the keyboard and touchpad. I immediately turned off the computer and left it closed with the keyboard facing down and placed it in the airing cupboard. Unfortunately I didn't remove the battery and didn't use any paper towel.
I kept it turned off for 5 days and have just turned it on. It appeared to be working OK. It boots normally and will then run completely normally for a random amount of time (usually sub 10 minutes and frequently much less) and then it appears to spontaneously short circuit and cuts power to the screen and/or touch bar. The computer remains turned on at this point. If a second screen is connected it loses power to this display, so it appears to be an issue of power rather a problem specifically with the MacBook screen.
What would people recommend? I'd be very grateful for any tips.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid you did just about all the wrong things & waited 5 days to find out. Repair shop, see if anything is salvageable.